# Как выбрать произвольные элементы двумерного массива? Си

Tags: c, массивы

Как из двумерного массива 9х9, наполненного случайными числами от -99 до 99 выбрать элементы из закрашенной области (как на рисунке) и найти из них максимальный элемент? Есть идеи?

[image: Массив 9x9 с выделенной областью]

Comment: в первую очередь нужно узнать диапазоны доступных значений, по которым и делать рандомную выборку

Comment: @sair Диапазон случайных значений: -99…99, но причем это тут?Нужно зарандомить полный массив 9х9, а уже потом искать максимальный элемент из закрашенной области.

Comment: @Igor Вопрос задан понятно, и его не нужно искать в комментариях. Если вы хотите увидеть полное задание, то так и напишите.

Comment: @Igor Я больше за результат беспокоюсь. Но и Ваш голос мне тоже важен;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдокод

```
max = m[0,0];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    if (m[i,j] > max)
      max = m[i,j];
  }
}
for (i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 9 - i; j++) {
    if (m[i,j] > max)
      max = m[i,j];
  }
}
```

Comment: А я думал что вы только на Js пишете :(

Comment: @Избытоксусликов You can write FORTRAN code in any language.

Comment: O.o а я и не знал

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за помощь, Igor. Вот рабочий код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Output(int *a[9])
{
    printf("Массив:\n");
    for (int i = 0;i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < 9; j++) {
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


int MaxInArea(int *a[9])
{
    int i, j, max = {0};
    max = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 9 - i; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("Максимальное число: %4d", max);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int Generation(int *a[9])
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0;i < 9;++i) {
        for (int j = 0;j < 9;++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 198 - 100;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, **mas = { 0 };
    mas = (int**)malloc(9 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(9 * sizeof(int));


    Generation(mas);
    Output(mas);
    MaxInArea(mas);
    free(mas);
    return 0;
}
```